# Retaining a value in an array

Tags: javascript

An element of an array disappears once the case is not met. I want the array to retain the value that was added in a previous case.

Code:

```
var x=[];
var y=1;

if (y===1){
    x.push([1,1]);
    y+1;
}
if (y===2){
    console.log(x); //I want it to print [[1,1]]
}
```

Comment: What did you do to debug your code? What is even the question?

Comment: @FelixKling I just used the code to show an example of what I meant .-.

Comment: How do you know that the array "looses" the value? I don't see you inspecting `x` "once the case isn't met". If you put a `console.log(x)` at the very bottom of your code you will see that `x` is `[[1,1]]`. So as far as I can see, there isn't a problem? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @FelixKling It doesn't print [[1,1]] tho -_-

Comment: It doesn't print anything because you put the `console.log` statement in the `if` statement whose condition is not fulfilled. Wasn't that on purpose? You said *"An element of an array disappears **once the case is not met**."*, so clearly it was intentional for the second `if` statement to fail, or not? Or what do you mean by "case"  and "met"?

Comment: @FelixKling aight thanks m8. didn't actually see that lol. felix kling the legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `if` condition is evaluated to `false` as value of `y` is `1`.

The statement in the first `if` block, `y+1` will not change the value of `y`.
To change the value of `y`, assign it to `y`.

```
y = y + 1;
```

You can even use, [increment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()), `++y` and `y++` or [shorthand assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment_2) `y += 1`.

```js
var x = [];
var y = 1;

if (y === 1) {
  x.push([1, 1]);
  y = y + 1;
}
if (y === 2) {
  console.log(x); //I want it to print [[1,1]]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment `y` properly. Using a post increment `y++`.

```
var x = [];
var y = 1;

if (y===1) {
    x.push([1,1]);
    y++;
}
if (y===2) {
    console.log(x); //I want it to print [[1,1]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, x certainly contains what you put in it, however, your console.log statement is in a block of code that is unreachable, so you will not see it printed to the console.

If you want it to enter the code block with the console.log statement you need to change: `y+1` to `y=y+1;`.

If you do not want to enter the code block with the console.log statement, but want to see the value of x, you need to add an additional console.log statement outside of the `(y===2)` code block.